# Django is removing html tags from the description field when we submit the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model, with description as a field.
Basically i am storing the data with html tags like

or any other tags for rich text supporting.
I have these tags stored in Database until i submit the form , On submit all the tags are lost, and only text is getting saved, after we submit the form. On submit of form I am calling form.save() along with other logics.
Tried following ways, gave strip=false in forms, and tried safe filter as wel;
and tried few ways with overwriting clean_description methods, nothing seemed to work

A solution to store text with tags even after submitting the form

Comment: You should provide the code of your form and model for us to see better what you do

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code, I can't provide exact solution but you'll need to mark your input "safe".
Django has default filters which will auto-escape any html unless you explicitly disable it.

Check out [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping) for more info, I'm sure you'll find a solution for your case.

Also keep in mind that there is a good reason behind auto-escape for html - you shouldn't mark anything safe unless you are 101% sure about it.